# Edit a Json File

Tags: php, jquery, json, gantt-chart

I am trying to use a jQuery gantt as a wordpress plugin. Currently I'm stuck on editing the data.json. I use a php form to populate a new item. When submitting the form, it will add data to the file, but behind the closing square brackets.

```
[{
  ...

 },
 {  "name"  : "Vermessung"
  , "desc"  : ""
  , "values": [
   {  "id"         : "5"
   , "from"       : "/Date(1363132800000)/"
   , "to"         : "/Date(1368655200000)/"
   , "desc"       : "Vom Beauftragen der Vermessung bis zur tatsÃ¤chlichen Vermessung"
   , "customClass": "ganttBlue"
   , "label"      : "Vermessung"
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

After submitting the form it looks like this:

```
[{
  ...

 },
 {  "name"  : "Vermessung"
  , "desc"  : ""
  , "values": [
      {  "id"         : "5"
       , "from"       : "/Date(1363132800000)/"
       , "to"         : "/Date(1368655200000)/"
       , "desc"       : "Vom Beauftragen der Vermessung bis zur tatsÃ¤chlichen Vermessung"
       , "customClass": "ganttBlue"
       , "label"      : "Vermessung"
      }
  ]
 }
]{"name":null,"desc":null,"values":{"id":null,"from":null,"to":null,"desc":null,"customClass":null,"label":null}}
```

This is the requested php Code which will adding stuff to the json:

```
$file = jQg_BASENAME_DIR.'/inc/data.json';
log_me('This is a message for debugging purposes');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$json = file_get_contents( $file );
$data = json_decode($json);

// convert form data to json format
    $postArray = array(
      "name" => $_POST['name'],
      "desc" => $_POST['desc'],
      "values" => array(
         "id" => $_POST["value_id"],
         "from" => $_POST['value_from'],
         "to" => $_POST['value_to'],
         "desc" => $_POST['value_desc'],
         "customClass" => $_POST['value_class'],
         "label" => $_POST['value_label']
        )
    ); //you might need to process any other post fields you have..

$json = json_encode( $postArray );
array_push($json, $postArray);
// write to file
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

I also can't establish the square bracket after `value`. How can I fix this?

Comment: why does your json file begin with `},` is it like you said end of the file so there must be more json at the top

Comment: I added the php Code and "optimized" the json output. ;-)

Comment: So you 1) read [{...}], 2) decode to PHP, 3) get the posted data into a PHP array, 4) json_encode the php array, 5) PHP push the JSON string to a string - that does not work the way you expect. Also you have nested objects and I assume you want [{[{old data},{new data}]}] so you need to show us the actual format and push to the PHP array and THEN json_encode

Comment: mplungjan, ok, and you're right. I want the data like [{[{old data},{new data}]}]. But how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment

```
$json = file_get_contents( $file );

// $json is now a string 

$data = json_decode($json);

// $data is a PHP object
// So lets call the second array $data->someArray
// since I do not know what it is called looking at your file

// convert form data to PHP array format
    $postArray = array(
      "name" => $_POST['name'],
      "desc" => $_POST['desc'],
      "values" => array(
         "id" => $_POST["value_id"],
         "from" => $_POST['value_from'],
         "to" => $_POST['value_to'],
         "desc" => $_POST['value_desc'],
         "customClass" => $_POST['value_class'],
         "label" => $_POST['value_label']
        )
    ); //you might need to process any other post fields you have..

// $postArray is a PHP object

// $json = json_encode( $postArray ); // do NOT convert here

array_push($data->someArray, $postArray);
$json = json_encode($data);
// write to file
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I use $data later to display the existing items. In this part I won't use it.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. One off topic question. Do you have a tipp how to formatting the json file after appending new data nicer? With line breaks and tabs?

Comment: Waste of spaces but try [json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your values field is an array of objects instead of an object (the encoding of a php associative array is a json oject). So for values to have square brackets instead of "values" => array() you would need "values" => array( array("id" => ... etc. ) )

As for your first problem you've inverted the json_encoding. First push your postArray into data, then json_encode data.

Comment: Thanks for your first hint. It works. Sorry for the question, but what do you mean with "push your postArray into data"??

Comment: you want add postArray to data so that the json file includes the newly created data, right? your $data is an array so you can do array_push($data, $postArray). And make sure you do that just before the last json_encode operation.